# how to convert mm:ss values in dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, object, python-datetime

I am pretty new to pandas and have a tabular data which has 3 columns where (`df.info()` gives `object` type) values are both in `s` and `m:s`. I would like to convert all `m:s` values to `s` values. I'll leave some examples to clarify.

**now:**

```
VT          FT          TTPF
1:28.8      1:17.2      30.4
1:06.4      1:06.2      16.8
38.6        26.2        10.8
```

**should be:**

```
VT          FT          TTPF
88.8        77.2        30.4
66.4        66.2        16.8
38.6        26.2        10.8
```

I'm sorry if I couldn't provide all the details. Feel free to request edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select only strings columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) custom function with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for filter values with `:` and then [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with casting to floats, multiple by 60 and sum together in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) for rows with `:`:

```
def f(x):
    m = x.str.contains(':')
    y = x[m].str.split(':', expand=True)
    return x.mask(m, y[0].astype(float) * 60 + y[1].astype(float))

c = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
df[c] = df[c].apply(f).astype(float)
print (df)
     VT    FT  TTPF
0  88.8  77.2  30.4
1  66.4  66.2  16.8
2  38.6  26.2  10.8
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elemetwise processing:

```
def f(x):
    if ':' in str(x):
        a, b = x.split(':')
        return float(a) * 60 + float(b)
    else:
        return float(x)

df = df.applymap(f)
print (df)
     VT    FT  TTPF
0  88.8  77.2  30.4
1  66.4  66.2  16.8
2  38.6  26.2  10.8
```